# Returning HTML from a javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I want to return HTML Code from a .js file.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
...
..
.


<script id="message-response-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="sender-message-line table-content vivify swoopInBottom">

        <div class="table-content-cell" id="ava">
            <img src="/static//img/pro_2.png" alt="DP" class="avatar">
        </div>

        <div class="msg-conatiner">
            <div class="actual-msg"></div>

            <span>Message</span>

            <div class="">
                <div class="message-seen text-right">{{time}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

...
..
.
```

JS

```
        setTimeout(function () {
            var contextResponse = {
                response:$('HTML CODE I WANT TO RETURN').html(),
                time: this.getCurrentTime()
            };
```

I can only return string files but when I want to return the whole HTML code that I wrote up there, nothing shows up

I tried :

```
response: $('<script id="message-response-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> <div class="sender-message-line table-content vivify swoopInBottom"> <div class="table-content-cell" id="ava"> <img src="/static//img/pro_2.png" alt="DP" class="avatar"> </div> <div class="msg-conatiner"> <div class="actual-msg"></div> <span>Message</span> <div class=""> <div class="message-seen text-right">{{time}}</div> </div> </div> </div> </script>').html()
```

Comment: use `$.parseHTML("HTML GOES HERE")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Jquery:

```
$("#yourDiv").load('yourhtmlfile.html #readMe');
```

And add the id to your html:

```
<div><div id="readMe"><p>text</p></div></div>
```